# Permiting all users to see the site

Tags: java, spring-security

It's my first time with Spring Security and I'm struggling with configuration. I want all people to see `/register` and `/login`, all other methods should be available after login.
I have method with `@PostMapping` which maps to `/register` (as you can already know you send nickname and password as a payload).

```
@PostMapping("/register")
    public Account createUser(@RequestBody Account account) {
        return accountService.createAccount(account);
    }
```

I have simple configuration which should let all users to see /register, but it doesn't.

My configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register", "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll();
    }
```

and still in postman I see:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/login">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <p>
                <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        </p>
                    <input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="72eb1e55-d2c7-455e-9046-19c7cb3c8e00" />
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/register");
    }
```